# MySQL find record through many table

Tags: mysql

In my case I have many table in my database.
My goal is to create a search engine where user can create all logical search he wants.
So I need to find a solution to generate all join based on user search critera.
In some case table has (1:n) links in other case (n:1).

One solution is to image all links and create all join, but I thinks it's a worse solution.
So if you have an idea, I'll very happy to read that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it like this don't know it is good or bad but a solution.

1. Create a new table containing all the searchable fields from various tables and reference to the record id to that table should also be stored in this table.
2. Insert the new record in this table whenever a new record inserted in those tables.
3. Search in this single table containing data from all other tables.

OR

consider to use [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. But in my mind, I'd like to generate sql request base d on user search. Therefore in my case, I have many record so add all in the same table may be very hard! Thank